# PHP's HTML ouput randomly cuts off and fails to load the full webpage

Tags: php, html, rendering, cdn

Been having an issue with one of my client's websites whereby the page will not fully render (the HTML source just cuts off if you look in "View Source") causing Javascript to not execute and content to be removed. The issue can be resolved most of the time by refreshing the browser a few times.

I don't have this issue on our staging server nor on my local environment so I was wondering if they'd be a server configuration which could be causing the issue. They are serving the website trough Encapsula CDN if that would effect it.

Comment: I have a feeling it's more of a server issue not programming.

Comment: In that case http://serverfault.com/ might be a better place to post. Or maybe http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. But I'm not completely sure if it's on topic there either. In any case wherever it belongs I think the question **as it stands** will be closed as **too broad**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that php short tags are ON at the server if you have used them in your code. I once had a similar issue since the PHP short tags were off. Once I set them to ON, things started running smoothly.

Comment: I do not use short tags for the reason that servers' configurations vary with regards to that setting you mentioned being disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, basically on our staging server we had a piece of code which was not found on the live server. It was a piece of legacy code which a previous agency had used which we left alone because we thought it wasn't being called at all.

The code capturing the output buffer and then manipulating the data captured before outputting it to the browser. This never caused an issue on the old server but started to when it migrated. I have removed the code and it seems to work fine now.